# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext for get method in Asp.netCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I create an web api project by Asp.net core, and i added an api controller to it(by the name `BlogController`), in blog controller i have a get method `GetAllBlog` this is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public IContext _context { get; set; }
    public BlogController(IContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Blog> GetAllBlog()
    {
        return _context.Blogs.ToList();
    }
 }
```

this is my IContext and model:

```
public interface IContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

and context:

```
public class Context : DbContext, IContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    { }
    public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and model:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

when i call `GetAllBlog()` i got this error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
>   what is the problem?

UPDATE: this is the `configurationservice` method in `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RestfullServices;Integrated Security=true";
    services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddScoped<IContext>(p => new Context(new DbContextOptions<Context>()));
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: You should also show the configuration where you add the db context

Comment: How and where you map IContext with your IoC? can you post it?

Comment: has to do with the new options you create when adding the IContext to IoC

Comment: @Nkosi what is ur mean? can u explain me?

Comment: ok before I do lets try something. try `services.AddScoped<IContext, Context>();` and see if that works.

Comment: @Nkosi it works, plz add ur answer with more explanation why its happend, for marking as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring the DbContext

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

you configure it to use specific options `options.UseSqlServer(connection)`

but when configuring the scoped context abstraction

```
services.AddScoped<IContext>(p => new Context(new DbContextOptions<Context>()));
```

a new `Context` is being created with a completely different configuration to what was configured before.

by changing how the `IContext`  is registered with the DI framework during startup like this

```
services.AddScoped<IContext, Context>();
```

The DI framework will use the `AddDbContext` configuration when creating instances of `Context` instead, which will have the options you want to use from startup configuration when creating instances of the DbContext.

the `Startup.ConfigurServices` would end up looking like this...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var connection = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RestfullServices;Integrated Security=true";
    services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddScoped<IContext, Context>();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();
}
```